# Dynamically Insert parent child records in a single DML

Tags: apex, dml, dmlexception, dynamic-dml

I'm trying to insert contact and account records in a single DML.
In my case I don't want to use the `.` operator Instead, I'm using the `put` operator to insert records.

```
Account acc=new Account(Name='Test Acc 8', External_Id__c='ext123');
Account a = new Account(External_Id__c='ext123');
Contact con = new Contact();
con.put('LastName', 'kk');
con.put('Account',a);
```

Above code results in error:

```
System.SObjectException: Invalid field Account for Contact
```

Although when I use:

```
Account acc=new Account(Name='Test Acc 8', External_Id__c='ext123');
Account a = new Account(External_Id__c='ext123');
Contact con = new Contact();
con.LastName = 'kk';
con.Account = a;
```

it works.

PS: `External_Id__c` is an external id field on Account.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use putSobject instead of put. The latter only works on normal fields, while the former is used to set relationship objects.

```
con.putSObject('Account',a);
```